# Rudimentary Infinite Series question

Tags: calculus

A ball is dropped from a height of 10m. Every time it bounces, it returns to $\frac{1}{3}$ of its previous height. When is the first time that the bounce is below $10^{-2}$m, and when is it the first time below $10^{-7}$m? To do this I would obviously need an infinite series. It would be modeled by $10 + \frac{10}{3} + \frac{10}{3} + \frac{10}{9} + \frac{10}{9} + \frac{10}{27} + \frac{10}{27}...$. I had the idea of factoring one of the fractions and turning it into a series, solve for the total distance, etc. How would I figure out what the question asks though? How do I tell when the ball first reaches any distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

I think the infinite series is not necessary in this case, more so, an infinite *sequence* would be needed.

Let $i$ be the number of bounces, $h_i$ is the height of the ball after $i$ bounces

$h_0 = 10, h_1 = \frac{10}{3}, h_2 = \frac{10}{3^2},..., h_i =\frac{10}{3^i},...$

thus you would need to find $i$ approximately for $h_i \leq 10^{-2},10^{-7}$.

$h_i = \frac{10^1}{3^i} \leq \frac{1}{10^2}, \frac{1}{10^7}$

$3^i \geq 10^3 , 10^8 \:\:\:\:\text{and then}\:\:\:\: i\cdot\ln(3) \geq 3\cdot\ln(10), 8\cdot\ln(10)$

for $10^{-2}$, $i \geq 3\cdot\frac{\ln(10)}{\ln(3)} \approx 6.2877$, so after the $7th$ bounce

for $10^{-7}$, $i \geq 8\cdot \frac{\ln(10)}{\ln(3)} \approx 16.767226$, so after the $17th$ bounce

I think your series represents the total distance travelled by the ball.

To model the total distance travelled by the ball is not hard either

Let $S_n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i$ then $S_n -\frac{1}{3}S_n = \frac{2}{3}S_n = 1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1}$

thus $S_n = \frac{3}{2}\cdot\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1}\right)$

and you can model the total distance by $2\cdot 10 \cdot S_n -10 = 10\cdot \left(2-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you. So I just need to find the $h_7$ and $h_18$th bounce? (I will also not accept the answer for now but will do later just in case more answers come in)

Comment: i edited my answer so you can see the calculation :)