# Ball bouncing infinite series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

A ball is dropped from a height of 10m. Every time it bounces, it returns to $\frac{1}{3}$ of its previous height. What is the distance traveled by the ball between its 20th and 100th bounce, and what is the total distance traveled? I've been told in another question that I can make a series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{3})^n$, so all I need for the first question would be to calculate $\sum_{20}^{100}(\frac{1}{3})^n$? So what would be the total distance and the distance from 20th to 100th bounce here? Thank you.

Comment: link to [the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053264/rudimentary-infinite-series-question)

Comment: Multiplying that by the initial height  and times two will give you the answer (since you need to travel up and down). Using the closed-form formula for the geometric series will save you a lot of work in the calculation :)